# how to stop and restart netty client while keeping connection with server?

Tags: netty

I'm using Netty server/client framwork. but i got a problem with netty client.
When i do `[ClientClass.connect();]` , the connection of the client and server is very good. However, when I want stop my client (NOT disconnect BUT Just Stop keeping connection) , i can't know how to solve it.

I just want it like this here
    `//[ClientClass.connect();]` --> connect to server(just connect)
    `//[ClientClass.stop();]` --> stop the client
    `//[ClientClass.start();]` --> restart the client

```
public class ContainerClient {

        String server;
        int port;
        String channelName;

        public ContainerClient(String server, int port, String channelName) {
            this.server = server;
            this.port = port;
            this.channelName = channelName;
        }



        public void connect() {
            EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

            try {
                Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap().group(group)
                        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                        .handler(new ClientAdapterInitializer());

                Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(server, port).sync().channel();
                byte[] bytes = channelName.getBytes();
                channel.write(bytes);
                channel.flush();

                while(true){
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String tmp = in.nextLine();
                    byte[] t = tmp.getBytes();
                    channel.write(tmp1);
                    channel.flush();`
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                group.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }
    }                                    

public static void main(String[] args) {          
   ContainerClient containerClient = new ContainerClient("localhost",port);
    containerClient.connect();   
}
```